# How to use a guard as an Middleware for authenticating users in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a webapp that have multiple roles so the one is admin which has a guard named "admin" I can authenticate fine but I just want to protect my routes so other can access it.

/ How i authenticate my admin /

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {

    // if passed
    // redirect to dancedrick media welcome dasboard page
    return ['redirect' => route('cmswelcome')];

   } else {

    // if faills
    // redirect to dancedrick media welcome dasboard page
     return ['redirect' => route('cmsregister')];
   }
```

I want protect this rountes

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {

   // redirect admin to cms welcome 
    Route::get('/cms/welcome', [
        'uses' => 'AdminController@cmswelcome',
        'as' => 'cmswelcome',
    ]);

});
```

Just like using 'middleware' => 'auth'

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the guard to the `admin` middleware:

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authentication-quickstart):

> When attaching the auth middleware to a route, you may also specify
>   which guard should be used to authenticate the user. The guard
>   specified should correspond to one of the keys in the  guards array of
>   your auth.php configuration file:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

In your case:

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']],function () {

   // redirect admin to cms welcome 
    Route::get('/cms/welcome', [
        'uses' => 'AdminController@cmswelcome',
        'as' => 'cmswelcome',
    ]);

});
```